# Using \chemabove/\chembelow with \vflipnext

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, chemfig

I have a molecule with a `\chemabove` command in it, and I'd like to mirror it vertically with `\vflipnext`. Everything is flipped just fine except for the atom positioned with the `\chemabove` command, which just keeps its position above the other atom. Is there a way to have this atom flipped as well?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
  % Dimethylamine
  \definesubmol{mol}{%
    -[::30]\chemabove{N}{H}-[::-60]%
  }

  % Normal orientation
  \chemfig{!{mol}}
  \par
  % Flipped orientation with wrongly positioned H
  \vflipnext
  \chemfig{!{mol}}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The molecules are drawn differently depending on the value of `\CF@split@state` which usually is `0`. `\hflipnext` sets `\CF@split@state` to `1` and `\vflipnext` sets `\CF@split@state` to `2` for the next molecule only. It is reset to `0` during the parsing of the molecule.

Below I define the commands `\chemflipbelow` and `\chemflipabove` that default to `\chembelow` and `\chemabove` but change roles if `\CF@split@state` is set to `2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\def\chemflipabove{%
  \ifnum\CF@split@state=\tw@
    \expandafter\chembelow
  \else
    \expandafter\chemabove
  \fi
}
\def\chemflipbelow{%
  \ifnum\CF@split@state=\tw@
    \expandafter\chemabove
  \else
    \expandafter\chembelow
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definesubmol{mol}{%
  -[::30]\chemflipabove{N}{H}-[::-60]%
}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{!{mol}}

\vflipnext\chemfig{!{mol}}\par\vskip5ex

\chemfig{R-\chemflipabove{C}{H}-\chemflipbelow{C}{H}-R}\par\vskip5ex

\vflipnext\chemfig{R-\chemflipabove{C}{H}-\chemflipbelow{C}{H}-R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As with 90% of your chemfig answers, I wonder why they aren't the package default already. :)

Comment: I (almost) never use `\vflipnext` so this has never been an issue for me :)